# AWS S3 not allowing to rename/move folders after Delete:Deny set as bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a bucket, in which I have set **s3:Delete*** to Deny, so that objects don't get deleted from the bucket. However, I want to move some objects to **a s3://bucket-name/trash** directory, and set a lifecycle policy to delete all the items in trash after 30 days.

I am not able to move those items, because the Delete Deny policy overrides it. Is there any solution that would help to bypass the Delete Deny policy so that I can move objects to just one folder?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show full bucket policy?

Comment: Bigger picture, you can configure object versioning on S3 buckets to prevent permanent deletion of objects. I think, in your case, move is 'copy then delete'. If you can't delete then, well, you can't delete. You can't override Deny policies. Explicit deny trumps all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/move-object.html),

> This action creates a copy of all specified objects with updated settings, updates the last-modified date in the specified location, and adds a delete marker to the original object.

The reason why your approach doesn't work is because `move` is essentially `copy` + `delete`. An alternative is to enable the bucket versioning, and apply a lifecycle policy to expire the previous versions after 30 days. Finally, change the permission to only deny `s3:DeleteObjectVersion`.

Comment: Hi Thanks,

I set the bucket policy to s3:DeleteObjectVersion and created a lifecycle policy. It fulfilled my requirements.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The bucket policy is not the best place to prevent objects from being deleted. Instead, enable Object Lock at bucket level, then set objects in *governance mode*, so they can't be deleted by normal operations. When you do need to move them, you can still bypass the protection with a special permission.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lock-managing.html